# in mac always getting zsh: command not found:

Tags: shell, osx-lion, zsh

I am using the z Shell (`zsh`) instead of the default bash, and something wrong happen so that all commands that used to work are no longer recognized:

```bash
    ls
    zsh: command not found: ls

    open -e .zshrc
    zsh: correct 'open' to '_open' [nyae]?
```

I don't know how to reset `zsh` or how to fix this. Here is the content of `$PATH` variable:

```bash
    echo $PATH
    /Users/Malloc/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.2.342:/usr/local/bin/mate
```

I cannot open the `.bash_profile` file nor `.zshrc` file, seems the only solution is to reset the `zsh`. Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

I even tried to reset `zsh` as indicated in [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14885/how-to-reset-a-shell-environment), but always got `command not found` error:

```bash
    exec zsh
    zsh: command not found: zsh
```

So what's going on? Why all commands are lost?

For reset shell i just add this in .zshrc and working fine

```bash
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.3p62/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: Shortcut: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20106583/basic-command-lines-on-mac-terminal-not-working (latest answer)

Comment: I got an Apple M1 processor and for me using "nano .zshrc" command  I was able to edit the file.

Comment: run this command->
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

Answer (score 574, accepted):

It's evident that you've managed to mess up your `PATH` variable.  (Your current `PATH` doesn't contain any location where common utilities are located.)

Try:

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:${PATH}
export PATH
```

Alternatively, for "resetting" zsh, specify the complete path to the shell:

```
exec /bin/zsh
```

or

```
exec /usr/bin/zsh
```

Comment: When I upgraded to Catalina I switched to the zsh shell and it messed up my paths to the point where I couldn't execute any third party apps I use.  I just had to modify the .zshrc file and add "export PATH=<<location of my bins>>" and did the exec /bin/zsh and all was good.

Comment: @devnull @Robert Walters I try your answer, but I still get ```zsh command not found``` when I try to access anything, is there another way solve this

Comment: @uyhaW FWIW, I just ran the `bash` command in my zshell environment, (so it switched to bash) opened my `.bash_profile`...then quit the terminal. restarted in `zsh` and it was suddenly working for me. IDK.

Comment: add `export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:${PATH}` begging of ~/.zshrc file, after save file run `source ~/.zshrc`

Comment: in Monterey this not works. Works with this command: `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"`. Hours and hours searching resolutions, I find. :)

Comment: zsh looks for .zprofile, so just create this file under your username and write your path or script you are trying to add -- basically create this by vim ~/.zprofile - under your user

Comment: To me this happened when I was using a script doing `for path in (...); do something with $path; done`. This worked perfectly in bash but zsh is apparently case insensitive when it comes to variable names, so $path messed up $PATH.

Comment: If npm's default directory has manually been changed, to resolve EACCES permissions errors when installing packages globally (https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally), you should add in your .zshrc file, on the export PATH line : $HOME/.npm-global/bin

Answer (score 56):

On MacOS BigSur
Click **Terminal** >> **Preferences**
change the from **/bin/zsh** to **/bin/bash**
Close and reopen the terminal

**FROM**
[image: Preference screen before]

**TO**
[image: Preference screen after]

You can now go back to .zshrc file to revert the last change you made

Comment: Still get same issue except `-bash`

Comment: This solution was exactly the one I needed. Thanks!

Comment: This worked in my Mac with M2 processor.

Comment: Great, its working for me.

I have added wrong path in zshrc fil.
Just removed the path and its working fine.

Answer (score 30):

The best solution works for me for a permanent change path.

Open Finder -> go to folder `/Users/<your user name here> /usr/local/bin`

open `.zshrc` with TextEdit:

> `.zshrc` is a hidden file so unhide it by `command`+`shift`+`.`

delete file content and type:

`export PATH=~/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:$PATH`

and save.

now `zsh: command not found` is gone.

Comment: if we open with TextEdit , mac will show following warning -> You don’t own the file “.zshrc” and don’t have permission to write to it.

So i open .zshrc file with VSCode and save as sudo.

Answer (score 27):

In your ~/.zsh config file include the path to your bash path file that contains your aliases. In my case it was including the line "source ~/.bash_profile" inside of ~/.zsh .

Comment: I don't have a `~/.zsh` file. Instead I had to put it in `/etc/zshrc`.

Comment: Same but mines in file: `~/.zshrc`

Answer (score 25):

1. Use a good text editor like VS Code and open your `.zshrc` file (should be in your home directory. if you don't see it, be sure to right-click in the file folder when opening and choose option to 'show hidden files').
2. find where it states:  `export PATH=a-bunch-of-paths-separated-by-colons:`
3. insert this at the end of the line, before the end-quote: `:$HOME/.local/bin`

And it should work for you.

You can test if this will work first by typing this in your terminal first: `export PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH`

If the error disappears after you type this into the terminal and your terminal functions normally, the above solution will work.  If it doesn't, you'll have to find the folder where your reference error is located (the thing not found), and replace the PATH above with the PATH-TO-THAT-FOLDER.

Comment: Aha, therein lies my mistake which led zsh to apparently "ignore" my `PATH` setting. From bash, I was used to prefixing directories inside my home folder with `~`. So it turns out for zsh I should instead be using the `$HOME` variable, like in your example.

Answer (score 16):

I solved my problem by reinstalling and/or add at the end of the `~/.zshrc` file:

```sh
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin && clear
```

Oh My Zsh is installed by running one of the following commands in your terminal. You can install this via the command-line with either curl or wget.

curl:

```sh
sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/master/tools/install.sh)"
```

wget:

```sh
sh -c "$(wget https://raw.github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/master/tools/install.sh -O -)"
```

Answer (score 14):

Works on **macOS 12 Monterey:**

You can manually edit `.zshrc` file and revert the changes you made to `PATH`.

- Open `TextEdit` app.
- Go to folder: `cmd + shift + g`
- type: `~/`
- See hidden files: `cmd + shift + .`
- select: `.zshrc`
- Revert changes, save file, and reopen terminal.

Answer (score 12):

My solution:

Change back to `bash`:

```
source .bashrc
```

next:

```
echo $PATH
```

copy this:

```
/home/frank/.asdf/shims:/home/frank/....
```

back to the `zsh`:

```
source .zsh
```

open `.zshrc`:

and paste:

```
 export PATH=/home/frank/.asdf/shims:/home/frank/....
```

restart terminal

Comment: In my case I had to reshim the asdf python install `asdf reshim python` and then it worked!

Answer (score 10):

I fixed the issue by opening the terminal preference general tab and changing the Command (complete path) to `/bin/bash` to default and then editing the `~/.zshrc` file.

[image]

```
export PATH="all your path inside the quotes"
```

...without any whitespace between the `PATH="` and save the file.

[image]

After saving the file, change the `/bin/zsh` in your command or select default
[image]

...and restart terminal and you should have your zsh shell working again!

Answer (score 9):

For me just restarting my terminal seemed to fix the issue.

Answer (score 9):

You can create a symlink in /usr/local/bin/

```
sudo ln -s $HOME/.composer/vendor/bin/homestead /usr/local/bin/homestead
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was having problems and this answer made me realize that I was not using `$HOME` and providing a relative path. Using full path with `$HOME` fixed my problem.

Comment: +1 for many simple use cases: Adding a symlink is the way to go if you're just looking to add one executable. If you're looking to manage multiple executables in a new folder, then adding on to `$PATH` is better in that use case.

Answer (score 6):

If you like me, you will have two terminals app, one is the default terminal with bash as the default shell and another iTerm 2 with zsh as its shell. To have both commands and zsh in iTerm 2 from bash, you need to do the following:

On iTerm 2, go to preferences (or command ,). Then go to the ***profile*** tab and go down to ***command***. As you can see on the picture below, you need to select ***command*** option and paste path of zsh shell (to find the path, you can do `which zsh`).

[image]

At this point you will have the zsh as your default shell ONLY for iTerm 2 and you will have bash as the global default shell on default mac terminal app. Next, we are still missing the commands from bash in zsh. So to do this, you need to go on your bash (where you have your commands working) and get the PATH variable from env (use this command to do that: `env | grep PATH`).

Once you have that, go to your iTerm 2 and paste your path on "send text at start" 
option.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin && clear
```

Just reopen iTerm 2 and we are done!

Comment: The reason why we added the export to "Send text at start" is that for someone reason for me, the path always reset to what it was before whenever I reopened iTerm 2. So this is a nice way of fixing it.

Answer (score 3):

### To permanently fix it, you shall go to `.zshrc` file which is in your root directory. You can do:

1. `cd` to return to your root directory
2. `code .` to open directory from your VS Code to be able to easily edit your `.zshrc` file
3. click on `.zshrc` file from your VS Code
4. (1) If you have not made any changes to this file previously, It shall look as follows:

> eval "$(rbenv init -)"
>
> export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
>
> export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"

OR

(2) If you did make any change, like adding some new PATH, then simply remove exactly that PATH.
In my case, I used to have a homebrew path as well, so I deleted it. So, now it looks the same as in the step *4 (1)*.

Answer (score 3):

For macOS, had to add `source $HOME/.bash_profile` to `.zshrc` file.

1. `$ code ~/.zshrc` (Opens `.zshrc` file on VSCode)
2. Add `source $HOME/.bash_profile` on top of the file and save it.
3. `$ source ~/.zshrc` to refresh `.zshrc`.

Don't forget to refresh.

Comment: This is wacky; `.bash_profile` should contain commands specific to Bash, and may have syntax which isn't compatible with Zsh (depending on how you have configured it).

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was by mistake the commented code was uncommented at the very first line.

```
# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
```

The hash was removed. After adding it back worked fine.

I just posted this here so someone might find this helpful. Because it's just start of the line and might be deleted by mistake like I had done. And seems there's no solution after trying several ways.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similiar problem when I installed ZSH on my ubuntu, I was getting the error **zsh: command not found node** when I tried to exec node or another command.

The solution for my was to open my `~/.zshrc` file and write the next code on it:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

Then I closed and reopened my terminal and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the .zprofile file and write into it

```
cd /
touch .zprofile
vim .zprofile
//Put Your Path
```

exit and Save
and after run this code into shell

```
 source ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the terminal also made the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using macOS, try to follow this step

if you write the code to export PATH in `~/.bash_profile` then don't miss the Step 1

Step 1:

- make sure `.bash_profile` is loaded when your terminal is an open, check on your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` (if you are using zsh), is there any code similar `source ~/.bash_profile` or not?. if not you can add manually with adding code `source ~/.bash_profile` in there
- Also make sure this code is on your `.bash_profile` > `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` if it not in there, add that code into it

Sep 2:

- make sure the `"Visual Studio Code.app"` is in the right place > `"/Applications"` or `"/Users/$(whoami)/Applications"`
- remove the old installed vs-code PATH `rm -rf /usr/local/bin/code`
- open "Visual Studio Code.app"
- `CMD+Shift+P` and then select `"Shell Command: Instal "code" command in PATH"`
- restart your Mac and check by run this `code -v`, it should be work

Answer (score 0):

**In my case I was using the variable `path` in lowercase!**

So in `/etc/profile.d` I was running a script that made use of the variable `path`. Because it was in lowercase I never thought it could mess up with the actual variable PATH. Be careful and do not use the variable `path` on your scripts.

Answer (score -1):

As others have said, simply restarting the terminal after you've made changes should reset and changes you've made to your ~/.zshrc file. For instance after adding function to open visual studio:

```
function code {  
    if [[ $# = 0 ]]
    then
        open -a "Visual Studio Code"
    else
        local argPath="$1"
        [[ $1 = /* ]] && argPath="$1" || argPath="$PWD/${1#./}"
        open -a "Visual Studio Code" "$argPath"
    fi
}
```

I was able to use the keyword code to open the program from the command line.

Answer (score -1):

A way to edit the .zshrc file without doing it through iTerm2 or native Terminal on macOS is to use a terminal in another application. For example, I  used the terminal as part of VSCode and was able to find and edit the file.

Answer (score -3):

Uninstall and reinstall zsh worked for me:

```
sudo yum remove zsh
sudo yum install -y zsh
```