# Switching to zsh shell -- `ls` ends terminal tab

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, zsh, fish

I'm switching from Fish Shell to Zsh.

I just went through a long process of converting a bunch of my Fish functions into Zsh, and most things are working, but I just noticed that when I type `ls`, it not only doesn't work, but actually ends the terminal tab session:

```
➜  ~  cd code
➜  code  ls

[Process completed]
```

Super perplexing, as I didn't (I don't think) do anything to mess with that command. Most other basic commands seem to work fine. Any ideas what might be causing this mess? I've put my new Zsh functions and my `.zshrc` file below.

The functions, which are mostly a bunch of Git/Zeus (a Rails tool) functions to make my life easier:

**~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/functions/functions.plugin.zsh**

```
##############################
######### ZEUS BASED #########
##############################

z () zeus start

rmz () rm .zeus.sock

rr () {
  if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
    r routes | grep "$@" 
  else
    r routes
  fi
}

zeus_on () {
  if ps aux | grep -v grep | grep 'zeus slave: development_environment'; then
    true
  else
    false
  fi
}

mg () r db:migrate "$@"

tprep () {
  if zeus_on; then
    zeus rake db:test:prepare "$@"
  else
    echo "Zeus is not running"
    rake db:test:prepare "$@"
  fi
}

s () { 
  if zeus_on; then
    zeus s
  else
    echo "Zeus is not running"
    rails s
  fi
}

t () {
  if zeus_on; then
    if [ '$#' -gt 0 ]; then
      zeus test "$@"
    else
      zeus test spec
    fi
  else
    echo "Zeus is not running"
    if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
      rspec "$@"
    else
      rspec spec
    fi
  fi
}

tt () zeus rspec --tag $1 spec

r () {
  if zeus_on; then
    zeus rake "$@"
  else
    echo "Zeus is not running"
    rake "$@"
  fi
}

c () {
  if zeus_on; then
    zeus c "$@"
  else
    echo "Zeus is not running"
    rails c "$@"
  fi
}

jt () {
  if zeus_on; then
    if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
      zeus tr spec:javascript SPEC="$@"
    else
      zeus tr spec:javascript
    fi
  else
    echo "Zeus is not running"
    if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
      rake spec:javascript RAILS_ENV=test SPEC="$@"
    else
      rake spec:javascript RAILS_ENV=test
    fi
  fi
}

# ##############################
# ############ GIT #############
# ##############################

gcurrent () git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD

gclean! () git clean -f -d

gd () git diff "$@"

gds () git diff --staged "$@"

gdh () git diff HEAD^

gr () git rebase "$@"

gri () gr -i "$@"

grc () gr --continue

gback () git reset HEAD^

gh () hub browse

gac () {
  ga
  gc "$@"
}

gacm () gac -m "$@"

ga () {
  if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
    git add "$@"
  else
    git add .
  fi
}

gp () git pull "$@"

gs () git status "$@"

gsp () git stash pop

gss () git stash save

gl () git log --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit "$@"

gco () git checkout "$@"

gcom () git checkout master

gpush () git push "$@"

gb () git branch "$@"

gbd () git branch -d "$@"

gc () git commit "$@"

gca () gc --amend

grb () git rebase "$@"

g () git "$@"

gcpick () git cherry-pick "$@"

grh () git reset --hard "$@"

gbdelete () git push origin --delete "$@"


# ###############################
# ######## CD SHORTCUTS #########
# ###############################

fish_dir () cd ~/.config/fish/

# Define code_directory in .zshrc
code () cd /$code_directory/"$@"

f () code "$@"

# ##############################
# ########### OTHER ############
# ##############################


tasks () ps aux | grep $@

b () bundle $@

ll () ls -lh $@

fs () foreman start $@

hcon () heroku run rails console

dtest () tail -f diagnostic.txt

sb () {
  if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
    sublime "$@"
  else
    sublime .
  fi
}

fish_edit () {
  sb ~/.config/fish/config.fish
}
```

> Probably unrelated, but also confusing to me. I get this warning when I open a new shell tab in relation to the uses of `grep` in that file. This didn't happen before with Fish:

```
usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
  [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
  [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
  [--null] [pattern] [file ...]
```

Finally, the `.zshrc` file that imports these plugins. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18428374/commands-not-found-on-zsh) (despite the different behavior) suggests that it might be a `PATH` definition issue, but I think I'm including all necessary paths in my `PATH`:

```
# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH=$HOME/.oh-my-zsh

export code_directory=$HOME/code/

ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"

plugins=(functions github)

# User configuration

export PATH="/Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin:/Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/bin:/Users/sasha/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin:/Users/sasha/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin"
# export MANPATH="/usr/local/man:$MANPATH"

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
```

**In response to the below question:**

```
➜  .oh-my-zsh git:(master) ✗ which ls
ls: aliased to ls -G
➜  .oh-my-zsh git:(master) ✗ typeset -f ls
ls () {
    ls -G -lh $@
}
➜  .oh-my-zsh git:(master) ✗ type ls
ls is an alias for ls -G
```

**UPDATE**

I've figured out **what** is causing it, but not **why**. It's this line:

```
ll () ls -lh $@
```

in my functions file. I figured that would run `ls -lh whatever-arguments-follow` when I typed `ll`. Any ideas why that woul raise an error when I ran `ls`?

Comment: What does `which ls` or `typeset -f ls` or `type ls` say?

Comment: Answered above -- looks like it's aliased somewhere? I'll look around for that, but I don't understand why `ls -G` would break the terminal tab anyway.

Comment: Could this be caused by a recursive (infinite) definition of `ls`? What happens if you alias `ls` to `/bin/ls -G`?

Comment: I added `alias ls=/bin/ls -G` to my functions file, opened a new tab, and tried it, and it killed the tab again, unfortunately.

Comment: Found what was causing it, but not why. Update above.

Comment: Try typing `ls` in a subshell, i.e., run `zsh` and then type `ls` at the `zsh` prompt. If `zsh` is printing an error message as it dies, that should let you see it before the tab closes (and take you back to the parent shell).

Comment: Your `ll` function definition should't cause the problem you're seeing, since you're typing the `ls` command, not `ll`. (Unless `ll` is being invoked indirectly.)

Comment: Yeah. Not typing `ll` at all, but it IS definitely the culprit somehow. If I comment it out, the error stops. And this is what I see when I run it in a subshell: `[1]    11628 segmentation fault  zsh`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so `ls` is both an alias and a function. That's not gonna work because they'll recurse. On my terminal, with ls being an alias and a function, when I run

```
ls
```

it thinks for two seconds, then I get

```
ls:1: maximum nested function level reached
```

Use either a function, or an alias, but not both.

**Edit** Oh, it looks like that could work, but the problem is that the `ls` function is recursive. It should read

```
ls () {
    command ls -G -lh $@
}
```

The `command` builtin makes sure you execute the actual command, neither an alias nor a function.

Comment: I don't see where I'm making it either an alias or a function. I've defined an `ll` function. Is that implicitly aliasing `ls` or something?

Comment: Someone else did that. Maybe your zsh is configured to source `/etc/profile` or `/etc/zsh` or `/etc/zshrc` or ... Do you have the `ENV` variable set to something?

Comment: Super weird. I don't have an `ls` function at all. Just `ll`, which should call `ls` directly. But when I added `command` it both a) worked, and b) replaced both `ll` and `ls` with the same function (essentially what I created `ll` to be). Again. I don't redefine `ls` anywhere, but it looks like `ll` is somehow redefining it recursively!?! (My only code is in the question above). Any ideas why that would be?

Comment: Literally just renaming my `ll` method to `lol` fixed it entirely. (So that both `ls` and `ll` work in their correct, separate ways). WEIRD. I poked around a bit more, and it looks like there's an `ll` function already defined somewhere, and redefining it caused the problems.

Comment: @Sasha If you want to know, in gory detail, what zsh does when it starts up as a login shell, run `zsh -l -x`. This should finally provide a clue where the aliases and functions come from.

Comment: Note that with `type ll` you can see, which ll is being used (for example, an alias to something, or a shell function), and `whence -f ll` shows its definition. This might give you some clue on where it is defined.