# zsh: command not found -- no longer have access to basic utilities and all installed softwares or packages from the terminal

Tags: macos, path, zsh, macos-catalina

Looks like I have managed to scramble my path variable when installing flutter, and now running yarn, shows `zsh: command not found: yarn`

This was the command I ran that I started experiencing the zsh command not found: 
`echo 'export PATH="$PATH:[PATH_TO_FLUTTER_GIT_DIRECTORY]/flutter/bin >> ~/.zshrc"`

I ran the code solution suggested by @devnull https://stackoverflow.com/a/18428774/1766068

`PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:${PATH}
export PATH` it would work when I open a new tab, but if I should restart the terminal it no longer works.

Comment: If you don't get the quoting exactly right, a command like that can really mess things up. Editing the file is generally safer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your `~/.zshrc` file in a text editor and remove the last line.  Then logout and login again.

Comment: Seeing that I couldn't open my .zshrc file, I had to use go through my finder, and in my main, and used CMD+shift. to show all hidden files.


```export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/Users/squarelabs/Projects/flutter/bin"
```

i removed this ```export PATH="/Users/squarelabs/Projects/flutter/bin"``` and it worked fine.

Comment: @Dansmog : You need to use a text editor which can easily edit dot-files. From the command line, you can use `nano`. Some editors can be configured to do so (`jEdit`, I think). You can also look [here](https://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2618/os_x_easily_edit_hidden_configuration_files_with_textedit/).

Comment: On macOS, my favorite GUI editor for things like this is [BBEdit](https://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/index.html). Even if you don't pay to unlock its full feature set, it's a really good script/config file/etc editor, and knows how to show invisible files in the open dialog. (But get the web-download version, *not* the App Store version -- the App Store version can't invoke your adminly powers to edit system files, due to Apple's security policy.)