# Messed up $PATH(i think) in zsh

Tags: path, zsh, path-variables

When i try to do ls in the terminal, it says command not found.

Before I broke everything, the output of echo $PATH was something like this:

`/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/gabrijelagavric/.gem/ruby/2.6.5/bin:/Users/gabrijelagavric/.rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin:/Users/gabrijelagavric/.rubies/ruby-2.6.5/bin:`

I was trying to follow along with some threads but I don't seem to understand what specifically I need to run to change my .zshrc file (this thread said to change PATH variable in .zshrc: [commands not found on zsh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18428374/commands-not-found-on-zsh))

So, I pasted this into the terminal:

`echo "export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/gabrijelagavric/.gem/ruby/2.6.5/bin:/Users/gabrijelagavric/.rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin:/Users/gabrijelagavric/.rubies/ruby-2.6.5/bin:" >> ~/.zshrc`

And then `source ~/.zshrc"`

But then i got this response

````
/Users/gabrijelagavric/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh:117: command not found: rm
detect-clipboard:33: command not found: uname
/usr/local/opt/chruby/share/chruby/chruby.sh:5: command not found: ls
/Users/gabrijelagavric/.zshrc:export:107: not valid in this context: /Users/gabrijelagavric/.gem/ruby/2.6.5/bin:/Users/gabrijelagavric/.rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin:/Users/gabrijelagavric/.rubies/ruby-2.6.5/bin:```
````

Comment: Don't use `echo ... >>filename` to edit a file; it's too easy to mess up things. If you want to edit a file, use a text editor.

Comment: This solved my issue thank you!

Answer (score 5):

The way I fixed this was following the answer provided by "user1934428" in their comment (though they didn't actually answer it so I don't know how to specify they resolved it"

Their suggestion was to edit the file in a text editor.

1. opened vs code
2. file > open
3. show hidden files (.zshrc) via cmd+shift+"." (for mac)
4. made changes
5. saved

Thank you user1934428,  your solution helped. Thank you to Mashuptwice and Chapner as well for answering as well.

Answer (score 0):

You've added the new `$PATH` variable as last line (`>>`) to your `.zshrc` file. Remove the last line of the file to revert the changes.

If you want to add a path to `$PATH` in the future, you can use `PATH=$PATH:/new/path/appended/to/variable` to add something to the variable, without completely replacing it.

Comment: Or in `zsh` ,`path+=( /new/path/appended/to/variable )`. Appending to the tied array takes care of all the corner cases involved in handling `:`s correctly.

Comment: Thank you! So, as of now my output from echo $PATH is /usr/local/var/postgresql@12

Comment: That doesn't seem right, I need to revert it back to ```/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/gabrijelagavric/.gem/ruby/2.6.5/bin:/Users/gabrijelagavric/.rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin:/Users/gabrijelagavric/.rubies/ruby-2.6.5/bin:``` . Is it safe to use echo to delete the line "/usr/local/var/postgresql@12" and add the stuff I need back in?

Comment: oh wait i just opened it via vs code and edited that way(fixed it). thank you for your answer though.

Comment: i followed the user1934428 's answer

Comment: @mostlyConfused from `man echo`: "echo - display a line of text" you cannot use echo to delete text from any file.

Answer (score 0):

Since I broke my path while tweaking things in my .zshrc, I could not enable "show hidden files" with the terminal command. Here are the steps I took:

1. Download an IDE of your choosing (`VS Code, Atom, Sublime, etc`)
2. Open `Finder` and navigate to your user (you can right click the folder name at the top to get a dropdown of your current folder and it's parents)
3. Press`⌘⇧.`(`Command-Shift-Dot`) to show hidden files.
4. Right click your .zshrc file and select "Open With"
5. Choose your IDE/editor
6. Make your changes and save