# zsh: command not found: fslview

Tags: terminal, zsh

I've installed the XQuartz and FSL.But when I run the fsl in the terminal, it shows "zsh: command not found: fsl". How can I solve this?

```
zsh: command not found: fslview
(base) md@mds-mbp ~ % fsl
zsh: command not found: fsl
(base) md@mds-mbp ~ %
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [in mac always getting zsh: command not found:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18428374/in-mac-always-getting-zsh-command-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I've revised my .zshrc profile to the exact PATH.It has been a mess.
Here is the solution I've referred to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18428774/18840553

Comment: Instead of describing the process of doing so subjectively as a mess, could you add a more objective description to your answer? Think about all the little things that you needed to learn over the last two days until you found the solution. Then look at your answer. If you start at 0, would you be able to find that solution with the amount of information contained in your answer? If not, then others probably also won't.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).