# Can't access the vue binary in my command line

Tags: vue.js, yarnpkg, vue-cli

I'm have some issues when trying to install Vue CLI on my mac device.
I am using the terminal and I also want to work with yarn and not with npm.
These are the commands used:

yarn global add @vue/cli

After doing that I got a message on the terminal where it says that it has been successfully installed. However, when I try to run one of the commands:

"vue" or "vue --version"

I get the following message => zsh: command not found: vue

Comment: It should work. Try restarting terminal. It's also possible you messed up your PATH variable. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18428774/1891677).

Comment: Unfortunately I still have the same issue after doing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update, i fount the issue. So basically I was missing one extra command.
This is the chronological order for commands:

yarn global add @vue/cli

export PATH="$(yarn global bin):$PATH"

vue

Answer (score 0):

You should use npm instead it will work.

```
yarn global remove @vue/cli
```

and then install using npm.

```
npm install -g @vue/cli
```

don't worry! on normally you can use yarn but for global use npm.

**solution - 2**

```
yarn global bin
```

add yarn global directory into your path

Comment: If I try running npm install -g @vue/cli i get into this error: npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/bin/vue.js' -> '/usr/local/bin/vue'