# CommandNotFoundError: No command 'conda mamba'

Tags: python, anaconda, mamba

I installed mamba yesterday via conda install -n base -c conda-forge mamba. But after installing it , my terminal is still saying zsh: command not found mamba.

What do I do?

I did mamba env create -f environment.yml. And was expecting to use mamba for package management.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [in mac always getting zsh: command not found:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18428374/in-mac-always-getting-zsh-command-not-found)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your headline seems to indicate you where trying to execute a command `conda mamba`.
Mamba is not an additional conda-command, but a replacement. So your command will start with `mamba`, not `conda`.

Please post your exact commands you where using together with the resulting errormessage.

Answer (score 0):

zsh uses the $PATH environment variable to find ncommands that you issue when you don't include a filepath in command.  There are exceptions, such as  built-ins and aliases and other stuff, but that's not important right now. And so, when you type the literal command `mamba` at the command line, each directory in the $PATH variable will be searched for an executable mamba file; the first one found will be executed.

Perhaps, after your install, the mamba file was created in a directory not found in your $PATH.   Consider looking for the file mamba and then adding the directory to your $PATH.

```
find / -name mamba 2>/dev/null
```

The above command searches your entire filesystem for the mamba file.  Errors that it reports will be ignored `2>/dev/null`.  I've done this because `find` will complain about a lot of directories you don't have access to.  Anyway, if `find` tells you where the mamba file is, add mamba's directory to your PATH.

```
export PATH=$PATH:<directory-of-mamba>
```

It will help if you add the above line to your .zshrc as well so any new terminal sessions will also have the PATH set properly.

Comment: Looks like mamba isn't working on Mac M1 chip. I used micromamba instead and it worked. But thanks! The issue on github: https://github.com/mamba-org/mamba/issues/1826

Answer (score 0):

Your headline seems to indicate you where trying to execute a command

```
conda mamba
```

Mamba is not an additional conda-command, but a replacement. So your command will start with mamba, not conda.

So instead of

```
conda update conda
conda update --all
```

you will do

```
mamba update conda
mamba update --all
```