# zsh: command not found - what to do?

Tags: python, macos, zsh

I have installed Python, also Anaconda. Using VSC or Mac Terminal I always get "zsh: command not found" error. I can't load any python packages either.
[image]

This is the first time I'm trying to use Python and without luck (coming from R, this seems exhausting).

I've searched lot's of solutions about bash and PATH and so on. But it's not clear what to do.

I'd appreciate any help.

add python to PATH file. I'm not sure I did it correctly though. Nothing has changed.

Comment: You can your answer in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18428374/in-mac-always-getting-zsh-command-not-found Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! There are too many solutions, and the ones I tried didn't work.

Comment: Please provide `PATH` value: `echo $PATH`

Comment: It gives me this weird dress: /Users/poshigetoshi/anaconda3/bin:/Users/poshigetoshi/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin

There are so many Python locations I'm confused which to use for path.

Comment: /Users/poshigetoshi/anaconda3/bin
/Users/poshigetoshi/anaconda3/condabin
/usr/local/bin
/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/Library/TeX/texbin
/opt/X11/bin
/Library/Apple/usr/bin
/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin
/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin
/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin